# Create uitable from dataset

Tags: matlab, dataset, matlab-uitable

I'm not able to create a table from a dataset using the uitable in matlab and I need help! Here's the problem:

I created a simple dataset :

```
names = {'John'; 'Henri'}
ages = [26; 18];
d1 = dataset({names, 'Name'}, {ages, 'Age'})
```

then I'have tried to create a uitable with this data and I wrote this line

```
uitable('data',double(d1))
```

but I received this error message:

```
??? Error using ==> uitable
Data must be a numeric, logical, or cell array

Error in ==> uitable at 56
        thandle = builtin('uitable', varargin{:});
```

So I tried again with

```
uitable('data',cellstr(d1))
```

but I got this error:

```
??? Error using ==> dataset.cellstr at 32
Error when converting 'Age' to cell array of strings.

Caused by:
    Error using ==> cellstr at 34
    Input must be a string.
```

I can not understand how I can create a uitable from a dataset with both numeric and strings entries.

Would someone be so kind as to help me?

Answer (score 2):

The errors are because you are using the [`uitable`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uitable.html) incorrectly. Here's a minimal example that illustrates how to do it.

```
dataCell={'John',26;'Henri',18};%# store data as a cell
colNames={'Name','Age'};%# names for each column of data

uitable('Data',dataCell,'ColumnName',colNames);
```

This should give you a neat table that looks like this

[image]

**EDIT**

To answer your comment below, if you are creating your dataset from a cell and an array as in your example, then you can directly combine both into a cell as

```
dataCell=[names,num2cell(ages)];
```

and proceed as above. If you already have `d1` as a dataset, perhaps not created by you, then you can create a `uitable` from that as

```
uitable('Data',[d1.Name,d1.Age])
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers.
Your advice is perfect, but I have a dataset array of 1255 rows and I cannot transform it in a cell array. Does it possible to make the same things but keeping the set as a dataset? thx